# $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (the set of all rational numbers)

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $$n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ Then $$n*1=n$$ and so $$n=n/1$$
Note $n$ and $1$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}$. so n can be written in the form of $$ z = m/n,\,\,\, \text{where}\,\, m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, n ≠ 0$$so $$n\in \mathbb{Q}$$

Is it enough to show like this? or do I have to prove more in general?

Comment: Looks good to me. (Except you over-use "$n$" towards the end.)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is completely fine, except at the end where it would have been better to write $z=m/n'$ so that one doesn't confuse it with the other $n$.